# Implement swipe gestures in apple watch using watchOS2.0

Tags: apple-watch, watchos-2, swipe-gesture

Hi I need to implement a functionality in my apple watch where when user swipes down will move from one module(InterfaceController1) to another module(InterfaceController2).And when user force touch menu should pop up and tapping on any button in the menu should present a model.
I am able to implement forceTouch menu option. But where as with swipe down to move to second module, i am not able to get any doc about this.
Please let me know if someone is aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:**

No, You can't.

**Long Answer:**

All `WKInterface` objects are proxy objects(aka Remote UI) that allows you to send queries to real UI Objects.

Reminds that the bundle that contains storyboard is separated with extension bundle. In sand-box concept, Your code that running on extension bundle can't access real UI Objects directly.

So there is no way to react against of user actions except that are available with interface builder(aka sentAction).